# rails scaffold not plural generate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffolding

I would like to generate a scaffolded controller, view and helper named with not pluraled one, but singular one. Howevery, I got pluraled named files like below. I know they are based on the rails convention, but I just would like to create a dictionary page.

```
$ rails generate scaffold_controller dictionary
  create  app/controllers/dictionaries_controller.rb
  invoke  erb
  create    app/views/dictionaries
  create    app/views/dictionaries/index.html.erb
  create    app/views/dictionaries/edit.html.erb
  create    app/views/dictionaries/show.html.erb
  create    app/views/dictionaries/new.html.erb
  create    app/views/dictionaries/_form.html.erb
  invoke  helper
  create    app/helpers/dictionaries_helper.rb
```

So, my question is "Are there any better ways or the shortest way to generate a singular named controller/view/helper files by command?"

What I want is just below. I'm wondering if I should make the files manually?

```
  app/controllers/dictionary_controller.rb
  app/views/dictionary/index.html.erb
  app/helpers/dictionary_helper.rb
```

Comment: why do you want to do that? for the URL's ? or the table names, or the controller name?

Comment: I just want to create a page. I don't need to add any tables(models).

Comment: so it's a single page? `domain.com/dictionary` ?

Comment: @gipcompany You can do it using infections, I have added a solution, hope you are looking for something like that.

Comment: @Mohammand, exactly. The website won't create a dictionary. The URL should be domain.com/dictionary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a railsway of doing this, you can use [`inflections`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-inflections) to document such exceptions:

**config/initializers/inflections.rb**

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.uncountable "dictionary"
end
```

Comment: File names are always in lower case letters by default!

Comment: Thanks, your solution is the closest answer for me!

Comment: Rails is a cool framework you know... This is why I love rails <3 :)

Answer (score 2):

Well without messing with any thing in rails you can set up the routes using `resource` instead of `resources` [more about that here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources)

You'll still use a plural controller name ( if you need processing ), but the URL will be singular, and you won't have all the actions like the plural `resources` ( more about that in the link ), if you just want one page then limit by using `only: :show`

```
resource :dictionary, only: :show
```

Then you don't even need the contorller, just create the file `dictionaries/show.html.haml` (or erb) and it would work

```
http://example.com/dictionary
```